# Как можно связать экземпляры класса и значения ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Есть ListBox,в который элементы добавляются  с помощью цикла,каждый элемент ListBox - свойства экземпляра класса в строчном представлении(экземпляров класса несколько и они объединены в массив).
Необходимо сделать возможность редактировать экземпляр класса, выбрав соответствующий элемент в ListBox

Comment: ваше описание ни  чем не говорит, приведите код и укажите, что вы хотите сделать. И что за класс ListBox? Вы его сами придумали или взяли откуда то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В компонент `ListBox` можно класть любые объекты, в т.ч. и разнотипные.
При этом в списке будет отображаться тот текст, который отдаёт виртуальный метод `ToString()` класса `Object` для отображаемого объекта.

(напомню, что класс `Object` является самым первым "прародителем" любого класса, даже когда Вы явно свой класс ни от чего не наследуете).

Соответственно, варианты решения задачи:

1. В своём собственном классе, который описывает решаемую предметную область, переопределить метод `ToString()`, чтобы он выдавал желаемый текст. Кидать в `ListBox` объекты этого своего класса, и `ListBox` будет отображать выдачу метода `ToString()`.
2. Если первый вариант не годится (например, нет возможности вносить изменения в существующий класс), то можно создать новый класс - обёртку, в котором переопределяем метод `ToString()` и даём ссылку на объект, подлежащий редактированию.
3. Если Вы собираетесь класть объекты одного типа (класса), и в этом классе есть публичное свойство с подходящим (для отображения в списке) текстовым значением, то указываем имя этого свойства в свойстве `ValueMember` компонента `ListBox`. (при отсутствии свойства с заданным именем текст элемента будет браться из `ToString()`)

В любом случае, чтобы получить доступ к выбранному объекту, обращаемся к свойству `SelectedItem` компонента `ListBox` - это свойство ожидаемо имеет тип `Object`, поэтому не забудьте сделать приведение к нужному типу.

Демонстрационный пример кода (простая форма с одним компонентом ListBox):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // вариант 1
        listBox1.Items.Add((int) 1);
        listBox1.Items.Add((long) 2);
        listBox1.Items.Add((char) '3');
        listBox1.Items.Add((string) "4");
        listBox1.Items.Add((Type) typeof(Form1));

        // вариант 2
        listBox1.Items.Add(new ObjectInfo(typeof(Form1), "'typeof(Form1)' (reflection)"));
        listBox1.Items.Add(new ObjectInfo(this, "This Form"));
        listBox1.Items.Add(new ObjectInfo(listBox1, "This ListBox object"));

        /*
            альтернативный (3) вариант: отображать свойство "Name";
            сработает для последних 4-х элементов списка (типы разные, но свойство с именем "Name" имеют)
            (для первых же 4-х элементов списка будет отображена выдача метода "ToString()", за неимением свойства "Name")
        */
        // listBox1.ValueMember = "Name";
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem is ObjectInfo oi)
            MessageBox.Show($"Выбран элемент: '{oi.Name}' класса '{oi.Object.GetType().Name}'");
    }
}

// класс для объекта-обёртки
public class ObjectInfo
{
    public Object Object { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    // ... прочие свойства и методы

    public ObjectInfo(Object obj, string name)
    {
        this.Object = obj;
        this.Name = name;
        // ... прочая инициализация
    }

    // здесь вернём то, что хотим видеть в "ListBox" по дефолту
    // (при закомментированной строке с "listBox1.ValueMember")
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"'{Name}' of type '{Object.GetType().Name}'";
    }
}
```